# weird issue with time function in C

Tags: c, linux, timer, epoch, beagleboard

I'm trying to get my Beaglebone Green to read an input from a certain pin, and when that pin sees a 1 to 0 transition (defined in pulse()), then it should set a timer.
I want to make my timer like this:

In idle, the timer is set to a `TIMER_HOLD` value (900000)
To start the timer, I set it to something lower then TIMER_HOLD.
Then it should decrement (with the `timerupdate()` function).
If it reaches 0 or less -which for an unsigned long is higher than TIMER_HOLD - then a trigger action is executed.

To test/debug this, I added: `printf("timer 1: %lld \n",timer[1]);`
And this works perfect... I see this output:

```
  timer 1: 900000
  timer 1: 900000
  PULSE
  timer 1: 5000
  timer 1: 4990
  timer 1: 4975
   ..........<truncated>
  timer 1: 1
  timer 1: 1
  timer 1: 1
  timer 1: 1
  timer 1: 1
  timer 1: 0
  timer 1: 0
  timer 1: 0
  timer 1: 0
  timer 1: 0
  timer 1: 0
  timer 1: -1

  TIMER TRIGGER
  timer 1: 900000
  timer 1: 900000
  timer 1: 900000
  timer 1: 900000
```

This is my c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/timeb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "../../BBBio_lib/BBBiolib.h"
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

#define INPUT_LEN 65
#define TIMER_HOLD 900000 // ms

void pin2array();
void timerupdate(void);
unsigned char pulse(unsigned char chkin);
unsigned char x,y;
unsigned char input[6][INPUT_LEN];

unsigned long long timer[10];
unsigned long long skew, prevtime, currtime;


int main(void)
{

        for (x=0;x<10;x++) timer[x]=TIMER_HOLD;

        iolib_init();

    while(1)
    {
            pin2array();
            timerupdate();
            if (pulse(0))
            {
                    printf("PULSE\n");
                    timer[1]=5000;
            }
             printf("timer 1: %lld \n",timer[1]); //THIS IS THE DEBUG PRINTF !!!
            if (timer[1]>TIMER_HOLD)
            {
                    printf("\nTIMER TRIGGER\n");
                    timer[1]=TIMER_HOLD;
            //      usleep(50000);
            }
            usleep(1); // CPU savings
    }
    iolib_free();
    return(0);
}
   void timerupdate(void)
 {
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    unsigned long long millisecondsSinceEpoch=
            (unsigned long long)(tv.tv_sec) * 1000 +
            (unsigned long long)(tv.tv_usec) / 1000;

    currtime=millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    skew=currtime-prevtime;
    prevtime=currtime;
    for (x=0;x<10;x++)
    {
            if (timer[x]<TIMER_HOLD) timer[x]-=skew;
    }
  }
 unsigned char pulse(unsigned char chkin)
  {
    if (input[0][chkin]==0 && input[1][chkin]==1 && input[2][chkin]==1 && input[3][chkin]==1 && input[4][chkin]==1 && input[5][chkin]==1) return 1;
    else return 0;
  }

  void pin2array()
  {
    for (x=0;x<INPUT_LEN;x++) input[5][x]=input[4][x];
    for (x=0;x<INPUT_LEN;x++) input[4][x]=input[3][x];
    for (x=0;x<INPUT_LEN;x++) input[3][x]=input[2][x];
    for (x=0;x<INPUT_LEN;x++) input[2][x]=input[1][x];
    for (x=0;x<INPUT_LEN;x++) input[1][x]=input[0][x];

    input[0][0]=(is_high(8,7));
    input[0][1]=(is_high(8,8));
    input[0][2]=(is_high(8,9));
    input[0][3]=(is_high(8,10));
   }
```

now the weird thing:
When I remove the `printf("timer 1: %lld \n",timer[1]);`
then I only see 
`PULSE`

on the output... the timer never triggers....

Any idea what's happening?

**system info:**

```
root@beaglebone:/# uname -na
Linux beaglebone 4.4.9-ti-r25 #1 SMP Thu May 5 23:08:13 UTC 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux

root@beaglebone:/# gcc --version
gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a `sleep()` or `usleep()` when you removed `printf()`?

Comment: Regardless of your problem - Maybe you should change that `timer[1]` to `timer[0]`?

Comment: Usually your symptom means non-initialized something or memory corruption. Try to run valgrind.

Comment: Your code sets `timer[1]` to 5000 but the `printf` immediately after the PULSE says it is 1645677788. This is not possible unless another thread is corrupting memory.

Comment: @JeremyP ; you're absolutely right, I used a wrong example for my output. I corrected this in the post. right after the pulse') the timer value is 5000....

Comment: @goodvibration; yes i know i should start my array elements with 0, but it's the same result. no matter if I  use timer[0] to timer[9] ....

Comment: @Gaurav: I'll give that a try as soon as I can .... let you know if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by reading /proc/uptime instead, then multiplying it by 10 (tenth of a second resolution is sufficient for my program)

I think the original thing didn't work because of a rounding error, or a conversion float to int.... not sure though